# ERROR in The target entry-point "ng2-carouselamos" has missing dependencies: - lodash.isequal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I just imported MatAccordion in my app.component.ts and added it in my home.ts and home.html to add expanding and collapsing icon, but I started getting the below error.

Error: The target entry-point "ng2-carouselamos" has missing dependencies:

- lodash.isequal

  at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
  at C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
  at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:28:29)
  at C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
  at SyncLocker.lock (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
  at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
  at Object.mainNgcc (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
  at Object.process (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)
  at NgccProcessor.processModule (C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:175:16)
  at C:\Users\pragya.richa\Documents\DigitalProject\configurator-project\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:146:18

I tried removing MatAccordion from everywhere also I tried manually reintstalling the ng2-carouselamos using npm i ng2-carouselamos --save but the error still persists. I am using angular 12

Answer (score 0):

It not working because you need to install `lodash.isequal`

In my case I install it and it works.

Comment: Could you provide more info on how to install it as well?